# Deleted answer, don't understand why

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4/25760180#25760180) and it was deleted without any explanation. Also there has been a downvote without any explanation. I'm not really understanding it as:

- It is answering the question
- It is providing a working solution
- It is well documented and formated
- It adds relevant information about what @Bacon2305 was looking for

I've been reviewing the [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and found:

- commentary on the question or other answers: ***this is not the case, as it provides a working solution with a different plugin. It was what @Bacon2305 was looking for:*** "Does anyone know of a working plugin for displaying Ads in a PhoneGap application? I;ve already tried this: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob with no luck.Thanks!"
- asking another, different question: ***same as before***
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses: ***not the case***
- exact duplicates of other answers: ***not the case***
- barely more than a link to an external site: ***not the case***
- not even a partial answer to the actual question: ***not the case***

---

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details. 
>   deleted by mod Sep 11 at 7:58

Comment: Just glancing at your existing answers, they seem to focus around a specific github repository that was created recently.  Consider that it may have gotten flags regarding spam - especially if it was a shorter answer that looked to be more publicity than answer.  (Note that I'm not a 10k user here and so am only guessing).

Comment: As @MichaelT suggested, it was probably marked as spam due to a github repo that you are a contributor of. Although spam should be marked only if it's unhelpful or promotional. The user asked for a "working plugin", if what your answer shows fulfills that request then this was in-properly deleted and should be restored.

Comment: It was not a short answer, it was fully documented one. I'm a contributor of the repository and logically I would like people to use it to help improving it as well (this is what open source is at the end...). But I've been also answering other questions not related to this repository. Anyway I think I'm not doing spam, please, let me know on the contrary: I'm answering what people is asking for...

Comment: @Miquel As far I can see, the deletion message thee is: `This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown`.

Comment: It sounds like you were answering a library-shopping question with an appropriate library, which isn't spam, even if it were your own library that you made money from. And reading your answer, it doesn't look like spam to me. But on the other hand, such a question is off-topic and shouldn't be answered in the first place.

Comment: The original question was asking for an alternative plugin and my answer offers an alternative working plugin, so imo this is not spam, just offering a different **free open source tool**. I'm also wondering why a downvote in this question?? And with no further explanation??

Comment: @Miquel: you're [not the only victim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289411/first-timers-answer-pointing-to-open-source-code-and-disclosing-affiliation-de) of moderators deleting answers that mention open source solutions developed by the answerer.

Answer (score 10):

Mentioning your own library as an answer to a question once or twice can be OK (as long as  you actually post an answer and disclose your affiliation); digging up *lots* of questions to post it on (especially resurrecting questions from 6+ months ago) crosses the line into excessive self-promotion.

Comment: There is something more which might have contributed: There was already a pruned answer promoting that same framework. (BTW: The single vote, -1, was a system-vote from the SPAM-Flag)

Comment: In fact everyone who is asking for a cordova plugin that integrates admob I'm answering with my solution because they are looking for it and I think it can help. Imo, 3 threads are not ***lots***, anyway this is something completly subjective. However, I'm taking note of it. Just to think about it, what should someone answer to someone who asks for a cordova plugin that integrates admob? Should that question be downvoted?, thanks.

Comment: The question would be a so-called recommendation question. They are off-topic for the site and as such should be closed.