# Systematically deleting answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074876/admob-integration-with-crosswalk/26081525#26081525) with a correct response (as the person was asking for an xdk plugin to integrate admob advertising).

My answer, proposing a plugin, has been deleted. There are other answers proposing different plugins. I think the correct should be to delete all answers regarding plugins or delete the entire question.

Leaving the answers regarding to one concrete plugin makes me suspect a lot, even more when it is not the first time it happens with the same plugin:

Please take a look at [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272333/deleted-answer-dont-understand-why) about [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4/25760180)

Comment: (not a 10k member, working off memory). So who was it deleted by? It should say.

Comment: If you think that another answer to that question is spam, then flag it as such.  If you think that the question isn't appropriate, flag *it* as such.  Due to your previous discussion you should know exactly why your own post is problematic and was correctly deleted.

Comment: @gunr2171 Andrew

Answer (score 10):

I am the one who deleted it.

I deleted it because you were basically just promoting your own plugin, when the question was asking about using a *particular plugin* already. That's why the one answer mentioned a plugin: It was the one being asked about.

The other answer, I did not notice until just now. It also just provided an alternative plugin. I've deleted it, too.

Note that there are a couple other problems, here; you have posted about your plugin a few times, and you have not always disclosed that it is yours. You've also posted many links that seemed not related, but just promotional. I edited out some of those where I thought the answer was good, otherwise.

---

I just noticed you asked about this here [just a couple days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272333/deleted-answer-dont-understand-why), which makes me wonder why you are asking again, after your posts were deleted again. Let me suggest that you take what you are being told to heart, this time.

Comment: I don't see in the question in any place which is the plugin it is asking for. So it could be the one I'm maintainig too (the structure is the same). You're right that I didn't mention it's mine, sometimes I forgot, I will do for next answers if it is the case.

Comment: @Miquel I **strongly** urge you not to look for most questions to promote your plugin on. Judging by the previous question about this you asked here, you aren't understanding how to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I would ask SO to apply the same criteria with all questions. That question seems to me like a spam the whole question but I'm not able to flag lots of questions as I'm not a high scored user. I'm not looking to promote the plugin, I'm just looking to offer an alternative to people who says it doesn't work with quality answers. And sorry for repeating, the question is not talking about which is the plugin, so I supose it's probably be the one I'm maintaining.